# matrix derivation

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

Given
$$
\mathbf{Z}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{H}\mathbf{W}
$$
where $\mathbf{Z}\in\mathbb{R}^{V\times d_n}$, $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{V\times V}$, $\mathbf{H}\in\mathbb{R}^{V\times d_{n-1}}$, and $\mathbf{W}\in\mathbb{R}^{d_{n-1}\times d_n}$, what is the matrix representation of
$$\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial \mathbf{H}}$$
? My understanding is that it should be $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{W}$, but their dimensions don't match.

Comment: What is given? What are the unknowns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be confused about how to define $\partial \mathbf{Z}/\partial \mathbf{H}$.
One reasonable definition is the tensor whose $(i,j,k,\ell)$-th entry is the derivative of $Z_{i,\ell}$ with respect to $H_{j,k}$.
Next, note that $$Z_{i,\ell}=\sum_{j,k}A_{i,j}H_{j,k}W_{k,\ell}.$$
It follows that $(\partial Z_{i, \ell}/\partial H_{j, k})=A_{i,j}W_{k,\ell}$.
Or, more succinctly, using the [outer product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#The_outer_product_of_tensors),
$$
\frac{\partial \mathbf{Z}}{\partial \mathbf{H}}
=\boxed{\mathbf{A}\otimes \mathbf{W}}.
$$

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\H{H_{kl}}\def\Z{Z_{ij}}
$Rename the dimensioning variables $\:(V,d_{n},d_{n-1})\to(m,n,p)$

and introduce the Cartesian basis vectors
$\big\{e_k\in\bbR{m}|\,f_k\in\bbR{n}|\,g_k\in\bbR{p}\big\}$

The gradient of the matrix $H$ with respect to its own components is
$$\eqalign{
\grad{H}{\H} = e_kg_l^T \\
}$$
which can be used to calculate the component-wise gradients of $Z$
$$\eqalign{
Z &= AHW \qiq
\grad{Z}{\H} &= A\,e_kg_l^TW \\
}$$
The fully indexed gradient is found by extracting the $(i,j)$ components
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\Z}{\H}
 &= \grad{(e_i^TZf_j)}{\H} 
 &= e_i^T\LR{Ae_kg_l^TW}f_j 
 &= A_{ik}W_{lj} \\
}$$

---

Another technique is to use a Kronecker product $(\otimes)$
to flatten $(Z,H)$ into vectors $(z,h)$
before calculating the gradient
$$\eqalign{
z &= {\rm vec}(Z) = \LR{W^T\otimes A}h \qiq
\grad zh &= \LR{W^T\otimes A} \\
}$$

Answer (score 0):

The *total differential* $DZ(H; {-})$ of a function $Z(H)$ is the best linear approximation of $Z$ at $H$. But $Z$ is already linear, so
$$
  DZ(H; K) = AKW.
$$
$K$ has the same dimensions as $H$. In index notation, writing matrices as $(1,1)$-tensors gives
$$
  DZ(H)^{ij}_{kl} = A^i_lW^j_k.
$$
The RHS is just the tensor product of $A$ and $W$, so we could write
$$
  DZ(H) = A\otimes W,
$$
but the problem with this notation (and the index notation) is that it isn't clear how $DZ(H)$ is supposed to be *used*.